# How to draw N-D cloud of dots in projection onto 2D space in Python?

Tags: python, plot, 3d, projection, pca

I have a table of numeric data, with 40 columns in each row, and approx 1000 rows in total. I would like to regard each row as coordinates in 40-dimensional space and draw this "cloud" of dots on the screen.

Of course, I need to project from 40D to 2D.

How to do that?

Also, I would like to be able to choose angle of projection, to see cloud from different "sides".

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: If you're asking about how to choose the projection, that's more of a math question than a programming question.  Collapsing 40 dimensions into 2 with a simple "squashing" projection is likely to look uninformative.  You might want to consider Principal Components Analysis, which is available in the scikit-learn library.

Comment: I am asking what Python libraries can do this. I don't want to implement math myself.